# Does products that can be subscribed to have to be created through iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, subscription

I'm building a iPhone app that will use a subscription model. I can see from the documentation that the subscriptions has to be created in iTunes Connect. Is this also true for the actual product that the user subscribes to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add every subscribable product in the iTunes Connect before you sell them to the user.